# Are the Server Fault ads disorienting?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Now I realize many of you will say, "what ad?" -- but, we recently got this email from a reader with less than 200 rep.

> Twice now in the last 3 days, I've gone to Stack Overflow and have been
>   confused by pages looking something like this:
>
> [image: Screenshot of Ad]
>
> I have to manually check that I'm still on stackoverflow and not
>   unexpectedly hanging out with a bunch of hippy sysadmin types. ;-)
>
> The advertisement looks like navigation.

What do you think? Disorienting? If so, any suggestions on how to make it more user-friendly?

Comment: Obviously this person's disoriented.  Hippies....

Comment: I think he is just wanting to be funny, hence the ;-). I mean, the "friendly war" between Cable Monkeys and Code Monkeys is as old as IT, and don't we love to sometimes take and give a bit of friendly smack talk to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made some changes, as these house ads were starting to bug me a bit too.

http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/try-sf_s09.png

- reversed logo order to prevent confusion
- made border gray instead of 100% black

Comment: I believe numerous BSOD issues can be fixed by changing the software involved. Certainly not all, but there's a lot of bad drivers out there. So going from driver v1.0 to driver v1.01 with the patch note: fixes BSOD, means there is a code fix for a BSOD.

Comment: Especially the border should help, the black was really to much.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't realize the logos were that large. Wow. ServerFault seems more prominent than the actual logo for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Switch the order, and downsize the logo. It'll be less likely to confuse if the logo isn't top-left and/or most prominent.

Comment: Resize good... but moving to the side kinda kills the copy ("Server Fault.... because ______.").

Comment: @Alex: I don't think it loses the punchline at all if it's reversed. ("...or you could try rebooting again: ServerFault", "Boy, what in the hell did you just do?: SuperUser", etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a yellow border or background like google does, to separate it from the rest of the page?

Comment: Not sure about yellow, but a different color background would be a good start.

Comment: Actually, now that I check, google uses a peach kind of colour for its ads.