# Where are the Ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I have never seen any ad on the stack exchange network and I refuse to use any form of Adblocking extensions. How can you afford this?

Comment: I looked at the related list to try and find a duplicate, and instead found ["Are the Server Fault ads disorienting?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15353/are-the-server-fault-ads-disorienting), ["Why has StackOverflow become so bloated with heavily distracting ads?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/why-has-stackoverflow-become-so-bloated-with-heavily-distracting-ads), ["Do Stack Overflow family sites have too many ads?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41131/do-stack-overflow-family-sites-have-too-many-ads), etc. You appear to be uniquely resistant to them

Comment: @Marv, currently they're only on the 'big three', that might explain it too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into the private mode of your browser and you'll see them soon enough if you don't log in; you should also be able to see them at the right side on the [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) pages. If you don't see them, something is blocking them at your side...

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. So only unregistered users can see the ads?

Comment: @Marv: Check out the [reduced advertising privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads).

Comment: @animuson: That doesn't apply to him, he has only 55 rep on SO and 6 here. A far cry from 200. He's seeing all of the ads that SE has to offer.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't understand how increasing advertising based on reputation benefits the site.

Comment: @Marv: It's not increasing, it's decreasing. That's why animuson links to the "reduced" advertising... Cody just mentions you don't experience reduced advertisements yet, which is why you should see all the advertisements that are in place. I just mentioned "private mode" such that this applies to anyone reading my answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread Cody's statement.